# Ideas.ArcGIS.Com - ArcGIS developer community

Tags: discussion

I posted this to the ESRI Ideas site:

> The resource centers are static and,
>   beyond a certain point, of little help
>   to developers (especially the search).
>   Provide stack overflow sites for
>   developer communities by platform and
>   include a wiki (like ScrewTurn or
>   Media Wiki) to post bugs, work-arounds
>   and best practices. Let the developers
>   run it for the community rather than
>   making it about marketing. It could
>   also promote the writing of
>   third-party developer books that
>   newbie GIS programmers can use to get
>   up to speed.

I got a response today that ESRI's interested in talking about it. If anybody has any suggestions or things worth bouncing off ESRI about this, comment or add an answer to this thread.

Comment: -1 Not a question.

Comment: Link to the Idea http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008IQO and a similar Idea that @Kirk-Kuykendall posted http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008A3B and this discussion on the meta http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254/ideas-arcgis-com-arcgis-developer-community

Comment: One thing that I really like about this site is that it is a mix of geospatial problems, people, and solutions from both the proprietary world and the OpenSource world.  I see some great cross-pollination of ideas and solutions going on.  It would greatly turn me off if this just became an ESRI focused site.  (heck, they are a company with 3/4 billion dollars annual revenue, and they can't come up with a solution?)

Comment: @DavidF: I agree entirely. My suggestion was to let developer customers - not ESRI - run the site but for ESRI to provide the site. GIS.se shouldn't become an ESRI site, but ESRI should provide a similar resource so we developers can use both to advance our work.

Comment: @MathiasWestin: Thanks for mentioning Kirk's post and the meta question. I duplicated the post here to catch the folks who don't know or visit the meta site.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suppose the same tension exists for Microsoft with respect to StackExchange.  Including  search results would be a step in the right direction.

I've posted this as an idea [here](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008IRH):

> Microsoft has incorporated
>   StackOverflow search results into MSDN
>   search. (See [Joel Spolsky's
>   announcent](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-overflow-results-featured-in-msdn-search/)).
>
> Esri should follow suit and
>   incorporate
>   https://gis.stackexchange.com/ results
>   into searches at resources.arcgis.com.

Comment: wow, I didn't know about the msdn<-so link. That is a great model for esri (and other vendors) to follow.

Comment: That would be cool, but I'm concerned that it might cause ArcGISers to overrun this site and chase others away.

Comment: I see a growing number of ArcGIS sites also running FOSS4G. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/postgis-arcsde-mixed-environment  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4771/how-can-i-obtain-the-following-effect-in-arcgis-or-any-free-software   IMHO,  questions posed by users at these sites will nurture FOSS4G growth, and will also motivate Esri (and other proprietary) vendors to improve their products.

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting idea. I see some issues.
1. Would it be a sub to this stack?
2. Would it degrade the use of this site?
3. Would it make using the resource center site easier?

Comment: I would expect it to help this site, since this site is not limited to ArcGIS. My suggestion was to let the community run it, but I'm not sure they want that.

Comment: They want "only" positive or successful implementations and I see them trying harder than they used to to help and get that going.

Comment: @Brad Nesom: I hope so.